# Is it possible to determine an Ethereum enode ID if you know the nodes IP/Port?

Tags: go-ethereum, bootnodes, node-discovery, enode

I have the IP/Port of a public node that I would like my node to peer with, but I don't know the enode ID.  Is it possible to connect using just the IP/Port or discover the enode ID using this information?